# how can I detect a list among a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists like:

```
List_PatientState
    [[1]]
          BirthYear Hispanic tEye tStatus tKidney         
    12604         2        0    1       2       2 

    [[2]]
         BirthYear Hispanic tEye tStatus tKidney          
    9252         2        0    2       1       1 

    [[3]]
         BirthYear Hispanic tEye tStatus tKidney          
    6613         2        0    1       1       1 

    [[4]]
         BirthYear Hispanic tEye tStatus tKidney        
    6265         2        0    2       2       1 

    [[5]]
         BirthYear Hispanic tEye tStatus tKidney          
    6202         2        0    1       1       2
```

in a loop I create a new list and I would like to neglect the list if it is available in my current list of list

for more information, consider this list that is created in my loop:

```
[[6]]
      BirthYear Hispanic tEye tStatus tKidney          
11773   2        0    1       1       1
```

This is similar to:

```
 List_PatientState[[3]]
```

I would like to detect such lists ,in my list of lists,So, I could reject it to add in my current list of lists.
Is there anybody to help me. 
I would be much appreciated.
the output of dput(List_PatientState):

```
> dput(List_PatientState)
list(structure(list(BirthYear = structure(2L, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), Hispanic = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), tEye = structure(1L, .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), tStatus = structure(2L, .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), tKidney = structure(2L, .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("BirthYear", "Hispanic", 
"tEye", "tStatus", "tKidney"), row.names = 12604L, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(BirthYear = structure(2L, .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Hispanic = structure(1L, .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), tEye = structure(2L, .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), tStatus = structure(1L, .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), tKidney = structure(1L, .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("BirthYear", "Hispanic", 
    "tEye", "tStatus", "tKidney"), row.names = 9252L, class = "data.frame"))
```

> 

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Also what do you mean *detect if there is similar list*?

Comment: try `unique()`on the list

Comment: do this function work for comparing a list in list of lists? could you please sent me a sample code?

Comment: Please share output of `dput(List_PatientState)` in the question description.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of answers

Answer (score 0):

First we create some sample data:

```
dat <- lapply(1:5,function(x) mtcars[x,]) #List of the first 5 rows of mtcars set
```

Then, if you have to use a `for loop`:

```
for (i in 3:6) {
   temp <- mtcars[i,]
   if(is.na(any(sapply(dat,function(y) all.equal(y,temp)[[1]])))) {
    dat[[i]] <- temp
 }
}
```

Basically checks in every Iteration if the `data frame` you create in the Loop already exists in your list and only adds `data frames` that are not contained in your list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response at first. but this part "all.equal(y,temp))[[1]]" shouldn't be "all.equal(y,temp))[[i]]"? I do not understand it.

Comment: You are right, edited. Its better to use `sapply` to return a vector instead of a list, also, the bracket squares should fetch the first elelement of the `all.equal` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your data

A list of vectors

```
List_PatientState <- list(c(Birthyear=2, Hispanic=0, tEye=1, tStatus=2, tKidney=2),
                          c(Birthyear=2, Hispanic=0, tEye=2, tStatus=1, tKidney=1),
                          c(Birthyear=2, Hispanic=0, tEye=1, tStatus=1, tKidney=1), 
                          c(Birthyear=2, Hispanic=0, tEye=2, tStatus=2, tKidney=1),
                          c(Birthyear=2, Hispanic=0, tEye=1, tStatus=1, tKidney=2))
```

#### New vectors to potentially add

```
newv <- list(c(Birthyear=2, Hispanic=0, tEye=1, tStatus=1, tKidney=1))     # duplicate values
newv1 <- list(c(Birthyear=2, Hispanic=0, tEye=2, tStatus=1, tKidney=2))    # unique values
```

#### Function to append if unique values

```
myfun <- function(L, V) {
              if (any(sapply(L, function(x) all(V[[1]] == x)))) {
                    return(L)
              } else {
                    return(c(L,V))
              }
         }
```

#### Tests

```
myfun(List_PatientState, newv)    # returns original list
myfun(List_PatientState, newv1)   # returns original list + newv1
```